# Herb identification (Possible Satureja viminea)

Tags: identification, herbs, mint

Hi I'm developing a plant database for my garden and I'm having trouble identifying this herb.

[image]

It has a minty taste and I believe I bought it as a mint variety.

Here is a close up of so you can see it better

[image]

Doing some research I found it could be Serpentine Savory, also called Jamaican Mint tree, latin name *Satureja viminea* but I can't find any information on the RHS website, that is my official go to for plant findings.

If anybody has information about this plant I'm looking for:

- Type (I would list it as a herb, if I'm wrong correct me)
- Sunlight
- Soil
- Moisture
- pH
- Propagation
- Pests
- Diseases

All this information for all my plants is based on the format the RHS uses, here is an example for Thyme if you would like to help me out:

https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/18213/Thymus-vulgaris/Details

Comment: Mentha varieties have square stems, and it looks like your plant has round stems... though its hard to be sure...

Comment: The plant in the background looks more like a mint than the one in the foreground - especially the dull look to the leaves (I can't remember seeing a glossy mint leaf, but then again, I don't grow them much). The background plant kind of looks like oregano.

Comment: The background plant is oregano, and if the foreground plant isn't related to mint then if it is any help it does have a very similar taste to mint, its actually quite strong.

Comment: I don't think that RHS database is a good reference. They have been proven wrong in many cases, and the database lacks many relatively common plants. Yes, they list zilions of plants, but majority is only with empty data (just latin name etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Satureja viminea** (serpentine savory)

Summary from [Dave's Garden](https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/142311/):

- Type:  shrub or small tree where not prone to frost (6-8 ft x 8-10
  ft)
- Light: Full sun to part shade
- Water: average pH:    5.6-7.5
- Propagation: Woody stem cuttings
- USDA zones 10a to 11

Comment: To be an answer, it should have the answer! Please add the name of the plant in your answer.

Comment: Thought it was implied. :)  But looking back, I have to thank you for pointing that you -  you are absolutely correct, it's confusing.  Plus my formatting sucks!